# Android How to track other users' current location Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making an android App which has a function of showing users' current location on Google Map.
I got trouble on tracking the users' locations and placing those locations on a map. I could get A user's current location and place it on the map, But have NO Idea how to do this for all the users' locations on the same time. 
I was thinking that I first send all the users' locations to the Parse.com and get them back and show them in a map, But I think this doesn't make sense because that is too much of work, In other words, I can't upload so many users' information on the same time (like per every second). 
Is there any other way to solve this problem?
Any tips Please!

Comment: Think firebase is more suited for such real time data handling

Comment: Thanks for reply: ) yes I have just checked this firebase, seems pretty useful (probably better than Parse.com). But, it might take another days or week to get confident to use this.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4h2to1cdbx087b/SAmpleApp.zip?dl=0 try this i have done similar few weeks back whole src code is in it,you might are gonna need few libraries to run it, using same hope this will help.

Comment: This is AWESOME example for my problem. Thank you so much Vivek Khare.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need :
[parse any wall sample project](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android) This projects included the code on how to solve your problem without any other libraries. It will sync with the database while you move within the app. so great because user will not even know it's syncing in the background. I have tested this so it takes about 2-5 seconds to update the map after you add a new location to the parse backend.